# What am I doing wrong using FindIntegerNullVector?

Tags: linear-algebra

Most of the time when I use FindIntegerNullVector with inexact numbers, I get useful results.
But occasionally, it seems to miss finding a simple null vector.
Example:

```
a = 13.4414592345679;
b = 3.402468500410153;
c = 3.7037718641975403;
d = 12.34799099999999;
Quiet[FindIntegerNullVector[{a b, c d}, 10]]
```

finds no integer relationship even though a b-c d < 3 * 10^(-14).
I was expecting a result of {1, -1}.
What am I doing wrong and/or how can I fix this line so that it will recognize that the two arguments are approximately equal?
I have tried varying WorkingPrecision and ZeroTest.

Comment: Try it on `SetPrecision[{a b, c d}, 15]`, slightly less than `$MachinePrecision`.

Comment: @MichaelE2 That seems to work. Thanks!

Comment: You're welcome. I haven't figured out a heuristic for predicting the tolerance needed, though.

Comment: Here's another way to round off the round-off error: `FindIntegerNullVector[{(a b + 2^8) - 2^8, (c d + 2^8) - 2^8}, 10]`. (Evaluate `(a b + 2^8) - (c d + 2^8)` to see the rounding error disappear. Try it also with `2^7`.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### A particular solution

This seems to work on the case at hand:

```
FindIntegerNullVector[SetPrecision[{a b, c d}, 15] 10]
```

> ```
> (*  {1, -1}  *)
> ```

But why the precision `15`?  The problem is to find, for real numbers $A$ and $B$, integers $x$ and $y$ such that
$$Ax+By=0 \,.\tag{1}$$
Suppose $A^*,\,B^*$ are floating-point approximations of $A,B$ resp. Then the problem is to find an integer point $(x^*,y^*)$ such that the line in the real $xy$-plane given by equation (1) passes "close enough" to $(x^*,y^*)$, where close enough depends on the error of the approximations $A^*,\,B^*$.  `FindIntegerNullVector` does this with some notion of "close enough" depending on the precision of the input.

### A general approach

Below is an adaptation `fINS` of an example in the documentation for `LatticeReduce` to solve the `FindIntegerNullVector` problem that diminishes the precision until we get a solution with a relatively small error (rough 1 ulp at the current precision).  In the couple of tests in which there is an integer null relation, it tends to overestimate the reduction in precision needed (pick a precision that is lower than necessary).  In the one totally random example, it did the reverse.  Consequently, `fINS` only approximates the precision needed for `FindIntegerNullVector` to reproduce the result of `LatticeReduce`/`fINS`.

```
fINS[z_?VectorQ] := Module[{a, b, err},
  a = IdentityMatrix[Length[z]];
  b = {{2, 2, 2}}; (* dummy values: fails While test *)
  err = 1;
  While[Abs[b[[1, -1]]] > 1, 
   b = PadRight[a, {Automatic, Length@z + 1}, 
     List /@ Round[-10^Precision[z]/err*z]]; (* scale the FP vec z and round *)
                                             (* which simulates FP round-off *)
                                             (* in integers *)
   b = LatticeReduce[b];
   If[b[[1, -1]] != 0, err *= b[[1, -1]]];
   ];
  {b[[1, ;; -2]], 10.^-Precision[z] * err}
  ];
```

#### OP's example.

Note `fINS` returns the null sequence and the estimate of the error tolerance needed.

```
{sol, tol} = fINS[{a b, c d}]
```

> ```
> (*  {{-1, 1}, 2.84217*10^-14}  *)
> ```

Map the tolerance to `Precision`:

```
reltol = Abs@tol/Max@Abs@{a b, c d};
prec = -Log10[reltol]
```

> ```
> (*  15.2066  *)
> ```

```
FindIntegerNullVector[SetPrecision[{a b, c d}, prec], 10]
```

> ```
> (*  {1, -1}  *)
> ```

We can increase the precision a little; too much, and `FindIntegerNullVector` fails:

```
prec = -Log10[reltol/2];
FindIntegerNullVector[SetPrecision[{a b, c d}, prec], 10]
prec = -Log10[reltol/5];
FindIntegerNullVector[SetPrecision[{a b, c d}, prec], 10]
```

> ```
> (*  {1, -1}  *)
> ```
>
> FindIntegerNullVector::norel: There is no integer null vector for {45.73414164516444,45.73414164516441} with norm less than or equal to 10.
>
> ```
> (*  FindIntegerNullVector[{45.73414164516444, 45.73414164516441}, 10]  *)
> ```

#### Second example, the `LatticeReduce` example perturbed by noise.

First, the exact problem:

```
FindIntegerNullVector[{Cos[4], Cos[1]^4, Cos[1]^2, 1}]
```

> ```
> (*  {1, -8, 8, -1}  *)
> ```

The perturbed problem: a tolerance of around `10^-14` or precision of around `14` should be needed.

```
SeedRandom[1];
coeffs = N@{Cos[4], Cos[1]^4, Cos[1]^2, 1} + RandomReal[10^-14, 4];
{sol, tol} = fINS[coeffs]
reltol = Abs@tol/Max@Abs@coeffs;
prec = -Log10[reltol];
```

> ```
> (*  {{-1, 8, -8, 1}, 6.15064*10^-13}  *)
> ```

```
FindIntegerNullVector[SetPrecision[coeffs, prec]]
FindIntegerNullVector[coeffs]
```

> ```
> (*
>   {1, -8, 8, -1}
>   {78257927, -626063069, 626063140, -78257876}
> *)
> ```

In this case the precision can be raised more:

```
prec = -Log10[reltol/10];
FindIntegerNullVector[SetPrecision[coeffs, prec]]
prec = -Log10[reltol/50];
FindIntegerNullVector[SetPrecision[coeffs, prec]]
```

> ```
> (*
>   {1, -8, 8, -1}
>   {-36655, -42915, 67969, -40144}
> *)
> ```

#### Third example, a random vector.

No relationship is expected but `FindIntegerNullVector` finds one with large norm.  The precision in this particular case needs to be lowered to get `FindIntegerNullVector` to return the same result as `fINS`

```
SeedRandom[0];
coeffs = RandomReal[1, 4];
{sol, tol} = fINS[coeffs]
reltol = Abs@tol/Max@Abs@coeffs;
prec = -Log10[reltol ];
FindIntegerNullVector[SetPrecision[coeffs, prec]]
FindIntegerNullVector[coeffs]
```

> ```
> (*
>   {{6, -6, -1, 1}, 0.0000326167}  <-- prec ~ 4.3
>   {-12, 7, 0, 6}
>   {-18811, -20158, 21650, 18102}
> *)
> ```

To get the smaller norm solution, we need to lower the precision:

```
Norm /@ N@{{-6, 6, 1, -1}, {-12, 7, 0, 6}}
```

> ```
> (*  {8.60233, 15.1327}  *)
> ```

```
FindIntegerNullVector[SetPrecision[coeffs, prec], 12]
FindIntegerNullVector[SetPrecision[coeffs, prec - 0.3], 12]
```

> FindIntegerNullVector::rnf: FindIntegerNullVector has not found an integer null vector for {0.6525,0.6331,0.6828,0.5664} with norm less than or equal to 12.
>
> ```
> (*  FindIntegerNullVector[{0.6525, 0.6331, 0.6828, 0.5664}, 12]  *)
> ```

> ```
> (*  {-6, 6, 1, -1}  *)
> ```

Comment: Very nice analysis. Which example in the documentation for LatticeReduce is fINS based on? I didn't see any example that looked close.  In fact, the documentation for LatticeReduce is very sparse. Do you know of any better documentation?

Comment: @StanleyRabinowitz The examples I based it on are the ones under "Applications". Sorry, the `Cos[]` example I cited is not from there (I forgot I had copied it from `FindIntegerNullVector`). `LatticeReduce` uses the [LLL algorithm](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/LLLAlgorithm.html) due to [Lenstra, Lenstra, Lovász (1982)](https://doi.org/10.1007%2FBF01457454). Some hints on `LatticeReduce` usage occur in the tutorial [Mathematical Functions](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/MathematicalFunctions.html), but they're still sparse.

Comment: @StanleyRabinowitz What I inferred (that is, guessed) from the examples is that, in effect, the first basis vector finds or approximates the desired integer null sequence (with small norm).  Put a `Print[b];` statement after the `b = LatticeReduce[b]` statement in the `While` loop.  (The `While` loop usually one makes at most two iterations.)

Comment: A question. `fINS` returns an integer vector. So what is the point of then calling `FindIntegerNullVector` with the returned `prec`?

Comment: @StanleyRabinowitz Principally to justify `fINS` does its job. The `FindIntegerNullVector` calculations that follow each `fINS` example show how well `fINS` did the following: "Consequently, `fINS` only approximates the precision needed for `FindIntegerNullVector` to reproduce the result of `LatticeReduce`/`fINS`." Secondarily, `fINS` does not restrict the norm, so if you want to do that, use `FindIntegerNullVector`. To just calculate an answer, regardless of size, use `fINS`; it also returns the error, which could be used to accept or reject the result (e.g., reject `fINS[{1., Sqrt[2.]}]`)

Comment: The following example shows fINS returning a precision that is too large. The precision 15 yields the null vector `{1, 0, -2, -2, 4}` which I know to be correct by independent means. However, the precision 20 returned by fINS is too, large and causes `FindIntegerNullVector` to not find the desired null vector.

Comment: ```fINS[z_?VectorQ] :=   Module[{a, b, err, tol, reltol, prec},  
   a = IdentityMatrix[Length[z]];  
   b = {{2, 2, 2}}; err = 1;  
   While[Abs[b[[1, -1]]] > 1,   
    b = PadRight[a, {Automatic, Length@z + 1},   
      List /@ Round[-10^Precision[z]/err*z]]; b = LatticeReduce[b];  
    If[b[[1, -1]] != 0, err *= b[[1, -1]]];];  
   tol = 10.^-Precision[z]*err;  
   reltol = Abs@tol/Max@Abs@z;  
   prec = -Log10[reltol];  
   Return[prec];  
   ];  ```

Comment: Help! I can't figure out how to enter a nicely formatted code snippet in a comment.

Comment: a = 16.05176286419753140;
b = 18.25227953135255277;
c = 13.94240841377744111;
d = 14.11925838957181156;

list = {a^2, a b, b^2, c^2, d^2};
prec = fINS[list]
Quiet[FindIntegerNullVector[SetPrecision[list, 15], 10]]
Quiet[FindIntegerNullVector[SetPrecision[list, prec], 10]]

Comment: @StanleyRabinowitz `fINS` finds a relatively large solution (norm ~6000).  `fINS` does not have a way to control the norm.  Try higher-precision input: `fINS[SetPrecision[list, 20]]`.

Comment: It's tricky (a slight change in the precision in my comment and it doesn't "work"), and I am not familiar with the problem.  You have this linear subspace that passes close to integer-coordinate points, but a close point found by the algorithm may be much further away that another point that would be acceptable.

Answer (score 1):

A solution is give the built-in the right amout of toleranz with a constant in another dimension:

```
FindIntegerNullVector[{a b, c d, 10^-14}, 10]

{1, -1, -3}
```

Comment: This is an interesting approach. To get the same functionality as `FindIntegerNullVector`  which has an argument to limit the norm of the integers found, I would have to add conditions like `x<10 && y<10 && z<10 && w<10`. I have tried this and it works, but it is much slower than `FindIntegerNullVector`.

Comment: The window for feasible tolerances is rather small: using a tolerance less than `0.99 * 10^-14` or greater than `1.05 * 10^-14` fails.  So it appears to be rather lucky that a simple power of `10` works here.  How does one determine the tolerance?